# DOS Batch File: If else goto statement understanding?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Making a batch program and I seem to have run into a problem with if and else statements.

I am trying to make it goto another line if anything else then "list" is typed.

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Code:

```
@echo off
:start
echo PROVOLONE-------------------------
echo ------------------------------TEAM
echo -------------PRESENTS-------------
echo The Simple Batch Program Collection
echo 2015 Provolone Team
sleep 3
echo. 
echo First, let's start off by listing what programs we have.
sleep 2
goto tutorial
:tutorial
echo type in "list"
set /p list="provolone>"
if %list%== "list" goto list else goto wronglist
:wronglist
echo I said type in "list!" not %list% !
sleep 2
goto tutorial
:list
echo.
echo All SBPC Programs as listed
echo starting with program names
echo placeholder
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are included in the comparison, so you need them on both sides of the comparison:

```
if "%list%"== "list" goto list else goto wronglist
```

Comment: That, and, to be official, there should be no space between the the equals in `"%list%"=="list"`